# Scrolling position changes after loaded more items to react-virtualized list

Tags: reactjs, scroll, infinite-scroll, react-virtualized

The following issues below point to the same problem I am experiencing:

[Scroll jumps to the top when List data gets updated](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/1755)

[InfiniteLoader jumps when scrolling up after loadMoreRows completes](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/1752)

[Adding new items to List causes Scrollbar Jumping](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/1745)

[(Using react-virtualized) vsx-registry: scrolling and selecting a tree-node jumps back to the top](https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia/issues/8101)

And of course [My SandBox Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cookies-7mwxcu?file=/src/App.js). When you are testing in my sandbox, scroll to the bottom as fast as you can and then stop to wait for loading. A single or multiple jumps will be clearly noticeable.

I am also cross-posting this on GitHub right now. If anyone would come up with a fix that would help a lot of people here using react-virtualized.

---

**Attempts**:

- When I remove the Cellmeasurer for both the content and the loader and replace row height with a manually defined function, the problem seems to disappear.
- To minimize the scenario, I removed the Autosizer and Windowscroller and left with only InfiniteLoader and CellMeasurer. The problem is still there. The jump occurs exactly when rendering the items Infiniteloader appends to the list.